# When using pipe getting "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Tags: windows-7, dos

When I run the following command (or any command with a pipe | in it) on my machine:

> dir | findstr "Directory"

I get the following message:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Running dir command or findstr command by themselves works just fine.

The volume label is:

> vol
>    Volume in drive C is OSDisk
>    Volume Serial Number is 685C-A5B5

The version is:

> ver
>   Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously mentioned by @dbenham You need to make sure your COMSPEC variable has correct values defined.

It should have the following value:

`%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`

You can check it by Right Clicking My Computer-->Properties--->Advanced System Properties-->Environment Variables

If You don't find COMSPEC there, create a new variable by giving the above mentioned value i.e. `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`

Good Luck

Comment: COMSPEC was there it just accidentally had the wrong value. I have changed it to %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe and that works.

Answer (score 3):

Check your COMSPEC variable. It should contain the full, absolute path (including file name) to CMD.EXE. Each side of a pipe is executed via a new CMD.EXE thread that is launched via the COMSPEC value.

Comment: That was it, thanks! Don't know how that environment variable got changed. But setting it back to point to full path of CMD.exe worked.

Comment: @highlandwolf - Don't forget to accept an answer by clicking on the check mark near the upper left corner of the answer. Only one answer per question can be accepted. That action lets others know the question has been answered, awards you 2 reputation points, and awards the answer poster 15 points. Once you reach 15 rep points you will be able to up vote as many answers as you find useful, even answers to other peoples question. An up vote gives 10 points to the answer poster.

Comment: This saved me a lot.  I was struggling with my wildfly which could not start and I had narrowed down to the fact that the one of the commands in "standalone.bat" was failing on using findstr.  Thank you