# Error on windows with pipe "|" character

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

For some reason we have a error on a Windows 2008 that cause simple command like:

```
dir | more
```

cause an error message:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I don't understand why it's happening.

Comment: I have just find the answer : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258695/when-using-pipe-getting-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is

Comment: *found Check your spelling.

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit my comment :(

Comment: This is why I have corrected the incorrect word within your comment.

Answer (score 0):

under my windows 8.1 more is a executable file more.com under c:\Windows\System32. please check if the file exists or if the Directory in the PATH.

Comment: That is not the problem, is not the more command, is the pipe character, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258695/when-using-pipe-getting-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is